# sqlite3_column_text(stmp,0) return really "(null)" string instead of NULL

Tags: sqlite

I do use below code to get the data from DB in CPP

```
char* return = (char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)

if(return == NULL)
   return false;
```

but the problem is even i insert `NULL` date to DB

I got real `(null)` string instead of `NULL` value.

such as `char* return = "(null)";`

So `if(return == NULL)` is always `FALSE`

Please help to to check the NULL pointer Thanks.

Comment: This means that some code wrote the string `"(null)"` into the database. The problem is with that code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i insert test data like this

char* InsertValue = NULL;
InsertDate("INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES(%Q)",InsertValue)

the %Q may be changed as "(null)",  how can i insert null point to DB?